# 'Kill'ing an app, from a sandboxed app?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, app-store, kill, appstore-sandbox

OK, it's as simple as it sounds :

- I've got a fully-working app
- I'm trying to 'sandbox' it, as per App Store's current guidelines.

The thing is :

- The app is executing in the background (as an `NSTask`), the `/bin/kill` command, and when I'm trying to execute it (WITH the sandbox entitlements enabled), I'm getting the following error :

> kill: 1298: Operation not permitted

Pretty obvious. However, is there ANY way this could be **bypassed** in a Sandbox-compliant app?

---

**Hint :** my goal is to be able to kill `app B`, from `app A` : is there any other way?

Comment: I hope there isn't a way. Not much of a sandbox if the app can affect other ones!

Comment: @BenClayton But what if the user explicitly consents? Shouldn't he be allowed to do it?

Comment: Even if you find any workaround, Apple will reject your application. My colleague made application which affects other application using Apple Script, and Apple rejected  this application.

Comment: @TomaszWojtkowiak I've already got an application in the App Store, and pretty popular to be honest, doing exactly that : killing apps. Well, it surely started in the pre-SandBox era, but it most definitely is still there. But then, Apple is Apple...

Comment: The application I am talking about was created lately. Apple rejected first version of this application in september, it was after Apple made sandboxing obligatory

Comment: @TomaszWojtkowiak I really can't speak for Apple; as they simply keep surprising me every time. However, simply put : blocking an app from doing anything 'unwanted' or mess with the system, sounds fine. But rejecting an app, doing something perfectly-legitimate, on user request, does not make much sense... at least to me. (SandBox for iPhone makes much more sense to me... but a Mac is not a phone...)

Answer (score 1):

Your app must be sandboxed, so it works in its own quarantined environment. It cannot kill any other app.

I have apps in the app store which use the kill command, but it is not sandboxed, so all I can do is bug fixes since 1 June.

Back then there was no guidelines against the kill command, but now it's simply impossible.